The emulator process for avd has terminated (OpenGL Core Profile not supported)
I have this problem for all my emulators. Wnen I create a new one I also have the problem.
Here is my log:
INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2024-07-07 17:15:04,948 [  84135]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - [9448:1780:20240707,171504.947:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\11285d6c-2b21-4cf6-9304-2d3feebf199d: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2)
2024-07-07 17:15:04,957 [  84144]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 20740
2024-07-07 17:15:04,958 [  84145]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - Android emulator version 34.2.15.0 (build_id 11906825) (CL:N/A)
2024-07-07 17:15:04,958 [  84145]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - Found systemPath C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
2024-07-07 17:15:05,193 [  84380]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - [1728:15516:20240707,171505.193:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\11285d6c-2b21-4cf6-9304-2d3feebf199d: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2)
2024-07-07 17:15:05,258 [  84445]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - Ignore IPv6 address: 3051:852d:7b01:0:9020:852d:7b01:0 (2x)
2024-07-07 17:15:05,259 [  84446]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\...\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_8_Pro_API_33.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-07-07 17:15:05,560 [  84747]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2024-07-07 17:15:05,688 [  84875]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
2024-07-07 17:15:05,690 [  84877]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0
2024-07-07 17:15:05,692 [  84879]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - OpenGL Core Profile not supported.
2024-07-07 17:15:05,821 [  85008]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - [1728:15516:20240707,171505.821:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\256e35e9-7833-4ab5-a935-719069882ef9: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2)
2024-07-07 17:15:05,821 [  85008]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - [1728:15516:20240707,171505.821:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\256e35e9-7833-4ab5-a935-719069882ef9: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2)
2024-07-07 17:15:05,821 [  85008]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - [1728:15516:20240707,171505.821:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: РЎРёСЃС‚РµРјРµ РЅРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ РїСѓС‚СЊ. (3)
2024-07-07 17:15:06,760 [  85947]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - [1728:15516:20240707,171506.760:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db\attachments\256e35e9-7833-4ab5-a935-719069882ef9: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2)
2024-07-07 17:15:06,766 [  85953]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-07-07 17:15:06,766 [  85953]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 8 Pro API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819

Updated:
I was able to run my emulator from the terminal with this command:
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator> ./emulator -gpu off -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_31

But I still don't understand a root of the problem.

Method 1
You don't have to completely delete the emulator when this happens. The files to delete should have a ".lock" extension:is here
You don't need to touch the configuration files.
You can easily find the files location by clicking on the arrow under the Actions tab (in the ADB manager), and selecting "Show on Disk".
Method 2
This worked for me:
Go to AVD Manager and click on the down-arrow on the right and click Stop. This stops the emulator and you can re-run it.
Method 3
There are so many answer but i just extending to give answer of this question. What happen is when i follow Android Studio instruction and try to delete that folder Or file but i am not able to delete it, So what am i do is that i open the AVD Manager and click on down arrow which is on right side as you can see in below screenshot and click on stop after click on start and its working fine. There is no need to restart or recreate the AVD.is here
